# How to remember the value from the pull down menu of what user selected?

Tags: html, perl

I prompt the user to select the date and click enter, but I am having difficulty to display what the user selected. In other words, date menu goes back to the default value. Here is the code:

Select the Starting Date

```
<select name="startmonth">
        <option value="1"> January </option>
        <option value="2"> February </option>
        <option value="3"> March </option>
        <option value="4"> April </option>
        <option value="5"> May </option>
        <option value="6"> June </option>
        <option value="7"> July </option>
        <option value="8"> August </option>
        <option value="9"> September </option>
        <option value="10"> October </option>
        <option value="11"> November </option>
        <option value="12"> December </option>
</select>
<select name="startyear">
        <option value="2010"> 2010 </option>
        <option value="2011"> 2011 </option>
        <option value="2012"> 2012 </option>
        <option value="2013"> 2013 </option>
        <option value="2014"> 2014 </option>
</select>


<input type = "submit" name="EnteredDate" value = "Enter">
```

Comment: How do you retrieve the value in the code? Do you use CGI, Dancer, Mojolicious, Catalyst?

Comment: i use CGI to retrieve the value...thanks

Comment: if($form->param("submit")){
    $startmonth = $form->param("startmonth");
    $startyear = $form->param("startyear");
}

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using [CGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI), observe the following cgi script.  It outputs the two select boxes that you've demonstrated, but will autofill their values upon a submit.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;

use warnings;
use strict;

my $q = CGI->new;

print $q->header();

print qq{<html><body><form method="post">};

print $q->popup_menu(
    -name   => 'startmonth',
    -values => [1..12],
    -labels => {qw(1 January 2 February 3 March 4 April 5 May 6 June 7 July 8 August 9 September 10 October 11 November 12 December)},
);

print $q->popup_menu(
    -name   => 'startyear',
    -values => [2010..2014],
);

print qq{<input type="submit" value="submit" /></form></body></html>};

1;

__END__
```